# Extract macro from Office document using pyUNO

Tags: python, libreoffice, uno, pyuno

I've got a Microsoft Word document with an embedded macro. I've managed to load a document using this example [Loading a document on OpenOffice using an external Python program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153843/loading-a-document-on-openoffice-using-an-external-python-program)

Now I'm trying to get macros code from my document, but can't figure, how to do this. I've stumbled upon interface that probably can be used (http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/document/XEmbeddedScripts.html) though it's unclear to me how to use it in Python.

So how can I extract macros text from document using Python UNO?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of LO you are using?
Normally, i would do something like

```
doc = desktop.loadComponentFromURL(url, "_blank", 0, () )


# the Basic Script Library/Libraries
the_basic_libs = doc.BasicLibraries

if the_basic_libs.hasElements():
    the_standard = the_basic_libs.getByName("Standard")

    the_one = the_standard.getByName("Module1")

    print(the_one)
```

But my version (LO 4.1.3.2) gives me a "no such element exception", though I can see and access the element using MRI (or the GUI).

Maybe a flaw in LO, uno ... or the fact, that we test with a *.doc